# Access Enum Array in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, enums

I have enum type :

```
EPosition = (eLEFT, eRIGHT, eUP, eDOWN);
```

and EPosition array :

```
position: array[EPosition] of Integer;
```

Assign :

```
if (Key = VK_UP) then
  begin
    position[eTOP]:= 1;
  end;

  if (Key = VK_DOWN) then
  begin
    position[eDOWN]:= 1;
  end;

  if (Key = VK_LEFT) then
  begin
    position[eLEFT]:= 1;
  end;

  if (Key = VK_RIGHT) then
  begin
    position[eRIGHT]:= 1;
  end;
```

Then here is my error point :

```
for I := 0 to 3 do
    begin
      if obSubImage.PreviewROI.position[I] = 1 then
      begin
        obSubImage.RenderROI.width:= abs(oldNewDiff.X);
        obSubImage.RenderROI.height:= formMain.imgPreview.IEBitmap.Height;
        obSubImage.RenderROI.x:= obSubImage.PreviewROI.x;
        obSubImage.RenderROI.y:= obSubImage.PreviewROI.y;
        panOffsetX:= 0;
        panOffsetY:= 0;
        obSubImage.PreviewROI.position[I]:= 0;
        renderLayer(0);
      end;
    end;
```

It gives an incompatible types : 'EPosition' and 'Integer'.
I know why it gives, i must write like;

```
    obSubImage.PreviewROI.position[eLEFT]:= 0;
```

But i don' t want to use IF-ELSE structure. I want to visit all index' s of array in LOOP. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `EPosition` type variable in your loop.

Instead of `i: integer` use `i: EPosition`

```
for i := eLEFT to eDOWN do
```

or

```
for i := Low(EPosition) to High(EPosition) do
```

Comment: thanks, also typecasting is work too. But your way is better :)

Comment: Or use `for i in [Low(EPosition)..High(EPosition)] do`